How to copy a contact
it is not rare that a new contact has the same informations as an existing contact except the name. So it would be great to easy copy a contact and then only change the name. That seems not to be possible in Civi. Does anybody has an idea for an work-around?
Thanks and kind regards,
Regina

You can use Entity templates extension
https://civicrm.org/extensions/entity-templates

Thanks! This extensions is good, but not exactly what we need. Anyway, we'll give a try.
